# enviromentService is undefined when calling fixture.detectChanges?

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I get an error when running this code:

```
   beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ SharedTestingModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useValue: mockTranslateLoader }
        })],
      declarations: [ RequestInfoComponent, StaticContentComponent ],
      providers: [{ provide: EnvironmentService, userValue: EnvironmentService }]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RequestInfoComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    componentHtml = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    environmentService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(EnvironmentService);
  });
```

The problem is the fixture.detectChanges(). If I remove fixture.detectChanges() then everything works fine, but I should run the code with it. I cannot remove it.

The error is:

> TypeError: this.enviromentService is undefined

This is my code in the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EnvironmentService } from 'app/shared/environment.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-request-info',
  templateUrl: './request-info.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class RequestInfoComponent implements OnInit {
  urlPrefix: string;
  constructor(private environmentService: EnvironmentService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.urlPrefix = this.environmentService.getWebContentUrlPrefix();
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the mock for the EnvironmenService? If you are not using one then why are you adding a useValue (btw it is useValue not userValue)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first `beforeEach` block, the first provider you have has a type:

```
{ provide: EnvironmentService, userValue: EnvironmentService }
```

Try changing `userValue` to `useClass` if `EnvironmentService` is a type, or to `useValue` if it's a value.

Comment: It doesn't work, we've changed it but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: @masterach there was a typo in my answer.  Try `useClass`, not `userClass`

Comment: this helps, now wait a second to do the full implementation

Answer (score -1):

Agreeing with solution offered by @BeetleJuice. As for the error you have:
TypeError: this.enviromentService is undefined
This is because you need to do your assignment as follows

```
component.environmentService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(EnvironmentService);
```

Comment: This doesn't help